# Export sheet as BMP

Tags: excel, vba, export, bmp

I get the below macro in my Excel document. I'm facing the error on exporting.

> Error: Object doesnt support this property or method

```
Sub pic_gen()
    Sheets("Email").Range("Print_Area").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlBitmap
    Sheets("foremail").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sChartName.bmp"
End Sub
```

Comment: what is your error please ?

Comment: @Fizik26 Object doesnt support this property or method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.Export` is a method which belongs to `Chart` or `ChartObject` class. You receive the error, because you try to use `.Export` method on `Selection` object which is of type `Range`. You should first create a chart, then you will be able to export it.

This may work:

```
Sub RangeToPicture()
  Dim chtObj As ChartObject
  Dim rngPrint As Range
  Set rngPrint = Sheets("Email").Range("Print_Area")
  rngPrint.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
  Set chtObj = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(1, 1, rngPrint.Width, rngPrint.Height)
  chtObj.Activate
  ActiveChart.Paste
  ActiveChart.Export ThisWorkbook.Path & "\sChartName.bmp"
  chtObj.Delete
End Sub
```